# MySQL - Ignore AND if no value exists

Tags: mysql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a MySQL query for Wordpress that gets Advanced Custom Fields data. If there is no result for one of the AND lines the whole query provides no result. I was wondering if I could add something to the query that would ignore the AND line if there's no result for that AND line?

```
SELECT DISTINCT post_title,
wp0.post_id as the_post_id, 
wp1.meta_value as _sale_price,
wp2.meta_value as _regular_price,
wp3.meta_value as ex_diameter,
wp4.meta_value as ex_center,
wp5.meta_value as ex_length,
wp6.meta_value as ex_alloy,
wp7.meta_value as ex_butt_1,
wp8.meta_value as ex_butt_2,
wp9.meta_value as ex_taper_1,
wp10.meta_value as ex_taper_2,
wp11.meta_value as ex_center


from wp_postmeta as wp0
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as wp1
ON wp1.post_id=wp0.post_id
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as wp2
ON wp2.post_id=wp0.post_id
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as wp3
ON wp3.post_id=wp0.post_id
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as wp4
ON wp4.post_id=wp0.post_id
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as wp5
ON wp5.post_id=wp0.post_id
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as wp6
ON wp6.post_id=wp0.post_id
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as wp7
ON wp7.post_id=wp0.post_id
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as wp8
ON wp8.post_id=wp0.post_id
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as wp9
ON wp9.post_id=wp0.post_id
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as wp10
ON wp10.post_id=wp0.post_id
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as wp11
ON wp11.post_id=wp0.post_id



INNER JOIN wp_posts as wpp
ON wp1.post_id=wpp.ID
WHERE wp1.post_id='39' 
AND wp1.meta_key='_sale_price'
AND wp2.meta_key='_regular_price'
AND wp3.meta_key='ex_diameter'
AND wp4.meta_key='ex_center'
AND wp5.meta_key='ex_length'
AND wp6.meta_key='ex_alloy'
AND wp7.meta_key='ex_butt_1'
AND wp8.meta_key='ex_butt_2'
AND wp9.meta_key='ex_taper_1'
AND wp10.meta_key='ex_taper_2'
AND wp11.meta_key='ex_center'
```

For instance; wp3.meta_key='ex_diameter' might not exists at all, but instead of getting a result with a blank ex_diameter the entire result is empty and returns no rows.

Comment: The SQL example in my answer showed  **`LEFT JOIN`** *not* **`OUTER JOIN`**.  Also, I think I'd want **`wpp`** to be the driving table. I'd list that first in the `FROM` clause... and do a `WHERE wp.id = '39'`. I'd follow the `FROM wpp` with a series of outer joins... **`LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wp1 ON wp1.post_id = wpp.id AND wp1.meta_key='_sale_price'`**. I don't see a need for `wp0`, you can get `post_id` from `wpp.id`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of ...

```
 INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as wp11
 ON wp11.post_id=wp0.post_id

 WHERE ...
 AND wp11.meta_key='ex_center'
```

You could use an "outer join" operation instead of an "inner join", move the condition from `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause of the join, and remove any conditions that require a non-NULL value in any column from wp11...

```
 LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as wp11
 ON wp11.post_id=wp0.post_id
 AND wp11.meta_key='ex_center'

 WHERE ...
```

With the outer join, if no matching rows are found from wp11, all of the columns from wp11 will be NULL. (Which is why we need to move the condition from the WHERE clause to the ON clause... the condition in the WHERE clause cannot be satisfied by NULL...

Repeat that same pattern for any table where it's acceptable for a row to be "missing".

---

Actually, using the `LEFT JOIN`, you'll need the "driving" table first. Probably want the `wp_posts wpp` table first in the FROM clause, and reference wpp.id in the outer join conditions. I don't really see a need for the `wp0` references, you can get post_id from wpp.id

```
SELECT
  FROM wp_posts wpp
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wp1 ON wp1.post_id=wpp.id AND wp1.meta_key='_sale_price'
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wp2 ON wp2.post_id=wpp.id AND wp2.meta_key='...'
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wp3 ON wp3.post_id=wpp.id AND wp3.meta_key='...'
  ...
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wp11 ON wp11.post_id=wpp.id AND wp11.meta_key='ex_center'
 WHERE wpp.id = 39
```

I have a feeling you are just starting to experience the *joy* of working with EAV. Let the fun begin!

---

To answer the question you asked... no, there's no way to get around an `AND condition`, not without modifying the condition, by adding an OR condition...

```
AND ( condition OR some_other_condition )
```

MySQL sometimes doesn't do too well (in terms of performance) with OR conditions.

Comment: spencer7593, Please see **** UPDATE **** in my question, thank you.

Comment: "MySQL sometimes doesn't do too well (in terms of performance) with OR conditions"  Very true, especially in Wordpress when the wp_postmeta table has a couple hundred thousand rows. :/